# Mongoexport file to front end user

Tags: mongodb, csv, express, frontend

So I have this command which works fine for exporting from my mongodb from the command prompt:

> mongoexport --db mean-dev --collection users --type=csv --fields "name" --out opt/backups/export.csv

My question is... how can I take advantage of `mongoexport` for a front end user? I would like to have the server be able to return the CSV file to the front end to be downloaded on a button click. Is `mongoexport` the totally wrong way to go about doing this?

I know AngularUI Grid allows for simple CSV exports of loaded data, but I'd rather not have to use a different library for tables. What I have already works pretty well as it is.

I'm on a MEAN stack (Mongo, Express, Angular, Node) so that's what I have available for me.

Answer (score 0):

as long as you use --host <:port> flag, and the port for the host running mongo is open for network access, you can run the mongoexport command from the client side.